# Standard comment for users who likely need to be merged

Tags: discussion, comments, user-accounts

When a new user account shows up, and it looks very similar to an existing user account, it would be nice to leave a comment saying something like "Are you this other user? If so, here's what you should do."

What should such a comment say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hi [insert username]. Your name looks familiar; is [this other account](link to other account) also yours? If so, please [ask for them to be merged](/help/merging-accounts). That way, you can keep track of all of your activity here in one place.

Comment: @Isaac Good edit. Has my stamp of approval.

Comment: I prefer "is [this other account]() also yours" to "is [this]() your account", because someone may not click through or realize that the link is to a separate account (not the one currently being posted from).

Comment: @msh210 Implemented.

Comment: I don't know if the wording "please find out how to get them merged" is so good, because it sounds like "we're not sure how to do it, so have a great time figuring it out!" ....maybe a better wording would be "please look into getting them merged"

Comment: @Shokhet, how's this edit?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Looks good.